# RSA криптография между Java и C# приложениями

Tags: java, c#, криптография, rsa

Почему при генерации RSA ключа длиной 512 бит в C# и в Java разная длина в байтах публичного ключа?

Пример кода C#:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);
XDocument xdocPub = XDocument.Parse(rsa.ToXmlString(false));
string publicKey = xdocPub.Element("RSAKeyValue").Element("Modulus").Value;

byte[] publicArray = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);
Console.WriteLine("Public Key Byte Array Length: " + publicArray.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Public Key Base64 Length: " + publicKey.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Public Key Text: " + publicKey);
```

Результат:

```
Public Key Byte Array Length: 64
Public Key Base64 Length: 88
Public Key Text: uELcIjgR6GpiayZ1wHruHOtO8dpg+xmg85VAvunWUEL+aifoyk9+CA/dez4UmuIwLEgRlpVoIIOD0e5i9v8lrQ==
```

Пример кода Java:

```
final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(512, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4));
KeyPair pair = keyGen.genKeyPair();

final byte[] arrayPublic = ((RSAPublicKey) pair.getPublic()).getModulus().toByteArray();

System.out.println("Public Key [origin] lenght: " + arrayPublic.length);

String publicBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(arrayPublic);

System.out.println("Public Key [base64] lenght : " + publicBase64.length());
System.out.println("Public Key [base64]: " + publicBase64);
```

Результат:

```
Public Key [origin] lenght: 65
Public Key [base64] lenght : 88
Public Key [base64]: ANuun1/CnOmk2ghsydz4cKvPCd7q0YqqeyjzLqtKx7QHqv1tFjJYsXquYGcY8zkaPsPBrRlCAJov7+J88GaFDKc=
```

Заметил, что в байт массиве ключа сгенерированного в Java присутствует нулевой байт в начале массива ключа.

Самое интересное, что если я отправляю ключ из C# приложения длиной 64 байта, то в Java приложении получаю ошибку "exponent is larger than modulus" в следующем коде:

```
try
{
    final KeyFactory kfac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    final BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger("здесь вставляется byte[] массив публичного ключа от C#");
    final RSAPublicKeySpec kspec1 = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4);

    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) kfac.generatePublic(kspec1);
}
catch (GeneralSecurityException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

При этом, если я добавлю нулевой байт в начало ключа перед отправкой из C# приложения в Java приложение, то со стороны Java приложения нет никаких проблем с инициализацией криптографии и шифровкой отправляемых данных. Но в этом случае я не могу декодировать входящие данные в C# приложении этим же экземпляром криптографии. Получаю ошибку "Плохие данные".

Подскажите, что я делаю не так и почему длина ключей разная?

> UPD 1: добавлен тест в Java

PublicKey взят из первого примера сгенерированного в C#.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String base64key = "uELcIjgR6GpiayZ1wHruHOtO8dpg+xmg85VAvunWUEL+aifoyk9+CA/dez4UmuIwLEgRlpVoIIOD0e5i9v8lrQ==";

        try
        {
            byte[] publicKeyArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64key);
            final KeyFactory kfac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            final BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, publicKeyArray);
            final RSAPublicKeySpec kspec1 = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4);

            RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) kfac.generatePublic(kspec1);

            byte[] array = publicKey.getModulus().toByteArray();

            System.out.println("Public Key [Array] lenght : " + array.length);

            String publicBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array);

            System.out.println("Public Key [base64] lenght : " + publicBase64.length());
            System.out.println("Public Key [base64]: " + publicBase64);
        }
        catch (GeneralSecurityException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

В результате инициализации RSAPublicKey в Java Base64 ключ не соответствует входному. Хотя по длине 65 байт. Но это работает только с `signum = 1`.

```
Public Key [Array] lenght : 65
Public Key [base64] lenght : 88
Public Key [base64]: ALhC3CI4EehqYmsmdcB67hzrTvHaYPsZoPOVQL7p1lBC/mon6MpPfggP3Xs+FJriMCxIEZaVaCCDg9HuYvb/Ja0=
```

> UPD 2: проблему C# генерации ключей RSA решила библиотека [Bouncy
>   Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/). У библиотеки есть
>   исходники поэтому я взял только RSA часть и внедрил в свой проект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Лишний байт

[`BigInteger.toByteArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray--) включает в результат знаковый бит числа:

> ... The array will contain the minimum number of bytes required to represent this BigInteger, including at least one sign bit, which is (ceil((this.bitLength() + 1)/8)) ...

Т.ч. да, нулевой байт в начале можно отрезать по необходимости. Сделать это можно с помощью `System.arraycopy`:

```
byte[] array = publicKey.getModulus().toByteArray();
//убираем лишний нолик
final byte[] keyBytes = new byte[64];
System.arraycopy(array, 1, keyBytes, 0, 64);
```

Посмотрите ответ [@Maarten Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/maarten-bodewes) на близкий вопрос на английском ([How insert bits into block in java cryptography?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18824707)), там приводится готовый метод для «нормализации» массива байтов с учетом ведущего нуля, также учитывается случай, когда массив короче 64 (вроде возникает только для приватных ключей).

### Плохие данные

Конструктор [`BigInteger​(byte[] val)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-byte:A-) также ожидает получить знаковое представление числа и пытается считать у ключа знаковый бит. Попробуйте использовать конструктор, который принимает знаковый бит отдельно [`BigInteger​(int signum, byte\[\] magnitude)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-byte:A-):

```
new BigInteger(1, /*байты ключа*/)
```

Похожие вопросы на en.SO:

- [how to build a rsa key with a modulus of 64 bytes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27187461)
- [How insert bits into block in java cryptography?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18819095)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Первая часть проблемы теперь понятна. А для C# есть какие-то варианты? Java часть является клиентской и не декодирует данные, а только шифрует и отдаёт. Мне важна C# часть.

Comment: @Rootware А какие проблемы с C#? Вроде в вопросе говорится о проблемах со стороны Java

Comment: проблема в том, что Java часть не может публичным ключом зашифровать данные так, чтобы C# приложение смогло дешифровать их. Даже если я добавлю это "знаковый" байт, то это решит "на половину" проблему обмена данными. Можно попробовать задать для обоих языков симуляцию со статическими ключами шифрацию и дешифрацию данных и сопоставить байт массивы. Но проблема очень странная. Ведь тот же Base64 не зависит от языка и кодирование/декодирование даёт идентичный результат.

Comment: @Rootware Пробовали задать ключ через нужный конструктор в Java (`final BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, ...`) и декодировать в C#? Что получилось?

Comment: добавил результаты теста. Шифрование проверю позже. Проекта нет под рукой. Но в тесте публичный ключ в Base64 извлечённый из контейнера RSAPublicKey не соответствует входному. Это нормально?

Comment: @Rootware Вы не убрали ведущий нолик из массива (обновил пример: https://ideone.com/nq8QHZ). Посмотрите [ответ Maarten Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18824707), там приводится готовый метод для «нормализации» массива байтов с учетом случая, когда он короче 64 (вроде возникает для приватных ключей).

Comment: Проведя пару часов поиска своей проблемы в англоязычной части интернета наткнулся на пост со схожей проблемой. В одном из ответов человек говорил о том, что в .NET криптография не всегда работает корректно в базовых функциях. Поэтому я решил воспользоваться сторонней библиотекой [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/). С ней генерация ключа происходит идентично как в Java - 65 байт (первый байт нулевой). Проверил на реальном обмене данных между приложениями. Нет никаких проблем с дешифровкой. Спасибо за информацию, хоть она и не решила проблемы, но ответ засчитывается.

Comment: @Rootware Пожалуйста, спасибо за отметку. Рад что разобрались. Может опубликуете Ваше решение отдельным ответом, наверное, кому-нибудь пригодится. Из вопроса я не понял в чем проблема со стороны .Net и не стал копать в эту сторону.

Comment: Нет смысла публиковать пример использования криптографии Bouncy Castle. Их полно в интернете. Я просто обновил вопрос и добавил ссылку на проект библиотеки. Проблема со стороны .Net - отсутствие, как оказалось, кроссплатформенности публичного ключа.